# What is the correlation between objective indexes and aggregated self-report measures of life satisfaction?

Tags: social-psychology, well-being, cross-cultural-psychology

The [Better Life Index](http://www.oecdbetterlifeindex.org/) and other indices seek to overcome the limitations of GDP in assessing social progress. They provide a composite score with which to rank nations on a range of indicators such as safety, environment, health, employment, economic activity, and so on.

Other researchers obtain self-report measures of happiness of life satisfaction (e.g., [Diener's popluar Satisfaction with Life Scale](http://internal.psychology.illinois.edu/~ediener/SWLS.html)). With care these scales can be aggregated over individuals to form a group-level measurement. For example, with careful sampling, a nation level estimate can be obtained.

I'm curious about these things:

- What is the correlation between aggregated self-report measures and objective indexes of life satisfaction?
- What explanation is provided for the size of the correlation in terms of how they are similar or different in what they measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [World Values Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/) seems like a good starting point for examining nation level life satisfaction and then correlating it with other indicators.

Diener (2000) summarises this research on

> mean levels  of life satisfaction for selected nations from the  World
>   Values  Survey  (World  Values  Study  Group,  1994),  conducted  with
>   representative  samples  of  approximately  1,000 respondents  per 
>   nation  between  1990  and  1993.  The  purchasing  power  parity 
>   figure  is  the  percentage  of  purchasing power (based  on a
>   standard  "basket"  of goods) that  the  average person  in  each 
>   country  can  buy  with  his  or her  yearly  income,  compared  with 
>   the  average  purchasing  power  of individuals  in  the  United 
>   States.  The  **correlation  between  mean  purchasing  power  income 
>   and  mean  life  satisfaction  was  .62  across  all  nations  in  the
>   survey**.  The  finding that wealthier  nations have higher levels of
>   reported  well-being  has  been replicated  several  times  (see 
>   Diener  &  Suh,  1999).  One  reason  that  wealthy  nations  may  be 
>   hap-  pier is that they are more likely to fulfill basic human needs 
>   for  food,  shelter,  and  health,  as  well  as  to have  better 
>   human-fights  records  (Diener  et  al.,  1995).

#### OECD Life Index

I performed a quick analysis of data from up to 36 countries from the OECD Better Life Index Site. You can download the datafile used directly from http://www.oecdbetterlifeindex.org/. The R code, data file, and output of this draft set of analyses is [available here](http://rpubs.com/jeromyanglim/oecd_index_draft_analysis), along with a list of the included countries.

I obtained the following correlations between other variables and self-reported life satisfaction (r is correlation; n is number of countries):

```
##                                               r  n
## Rooms.per.person                           0.70 30
## Personal.earnings                          0.67 34
## Employment.rate                            0.63 36
## Households.income                          0.59 32
## Water.quality                              0.59 36
## Long.term.unemployment.rate               -0.58 34
## Self.reported.health                       0.58 34
## Life.expectancy                            0.57 36
## Dwellings.with.basic.facilities            0.54 32
## Social.network                             0.50 36
## Time.devoted.to.leisure.and.personal.care  0.43 21
## Household.financial.wealth                 0.41 31
## Voter.turn.out                             0.36 36
## Educational.attainment                     0.22 35
## Students..skills                           0.21 36
## Air.pollution                             -0.18 36
## Housing.expenditure                        0.12 32
## Years.in.education                         0.12 35
## Consultation.on.rule.making                0.12 35
## Employees.working.very.long.hours         -0.09 33
## Job.security                               0.08 32
## Homicide.rate                             -0.07 36
## Assault.rate                              -0.02 36
```

#### References

- Diener, E. (2000). Subjective well-being: The science of happiness and a proposal for a national index. American psychologist, 55, 34.
- Diener,  E.,  Diener,  M.,  &  Diener,  C.  (1995).  Factors  predicting  the 
  subjective  well-being  of  nations.  Journal  of Personality  and  Social 
  Psychology,  69,  851-864.
- Diener,  E.,  &  Sub,  E.  (1999).  Societies we  live  in: International  compar- 
  isons. In  D.  Kahneman, E.  Diener,  &  N.  Schwarz  (Eds.),  Well-being: 
  The foundations  of  hedonic  psychology  (pp.  434-452).  New  York: 
  Russell Sage  Foundation.
- World Values Study Group. (1994).  World Values Survey,  1981-1994  and 
  1990-1993  [Computer file,  ICPSR  version].  Ann Arbor,  MI:  Institute 
  for  Social  Research.